# Flux Integral - where did I go wrong?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, differential-forms

> S is the graph $z=25-(x^2+y^2)$ over the disk $x^2+y^2\leq 9$ and $\varphi = z^2dx\wedge dy$. Find $\int_S \varphi$.

According to the book the answer is $3843\pi$, but the answer I got is different.

What I did: First define $k(x,y)=(x,y,25-(x^2+y^2))$ then $k_x=(1,0,-2x)$ and $k_y=(0,1,-2y)$.

Now, I have that $\varphi (k_x,k_y)=(25-(x^2+y^2))^2dx\wedge dy (k_x,k_y)=(25-(x^2+y^2))^2$.

I ought to find $\int_S\varphi$ which will be given by $$\int_S\varphi=\int_0^3\int_0^{\sqrt{9-y^2}}625-50(x^2+y^2)+(x^2+y^2)^2dxdy$$.

To make it easier, I changed to polar coordinates: $x=r\cos\phi,y=r\sin\psi$. Then I have

$$\int_S\varphi = \int_0^{\color{red}{2\pi}}\int_0^3625r-50r^3+r^5drd\phi\\=\int_0^{\color{red}{2\pi}}\left(\frac{625}{2}(3)^2-\frac{50}{4}(3)^4+\frac{1}{6}(3)^6\right)d\phi\\=\int_0^{\color{red}{2\pi}}\left(\frac{5625}{2}-\frac{4050}{4}+\frac{726}{6}\right)d\varphi\\=\int_0^{\color{red}{2\pi}} 1921\; d\phi\\=3842\pi.$$

Looks like I have missed something, maybe my change to polar coordinates is wrong or there's another mistake that I cannot see.

**Update:Fixed the limits of integration**

Comment: You're quite nearly off by half. This suggests to me that you forgot to integrate over the bottom half of the circle. (Note that you integrated from $0$ to $\sqrt{9-y^2}$ when maybe you should be integrating from $-\sqrt{9-y^2}$ to $+\sqrt{9-y^2}$. This will change your limits on $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$ to $0$ to $2\pi$.)

Comment: Yes, you're right!. A lot of exercises were only about the top half so I naively took the same domain. Still, the answer is wrong, because I would get $3842\pi$ instead of the answer from the book :(.

Comment: The $3$ could be a typo and should be a $2$ like you have in your answer. I can't see what if anything is wrong. Typos like this are common in textbooks. Hopefully someone else can chime in on the matter. Also.. Nice username/picture.

Comment: Oh it seems you made an algebraic error in your second to last step. Nothing serious :)

Comment: No, the error is that $726=729$ !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3843\pi$ is correct. I would recommend doing the integration slightly more economically. We want 
$$2\pi \int_0^3 (25-r^2)^2 r\,dr = \pi \int_{16}^{25} u^2\, du,$$
having made the substitution $u=25-r^2$. :)

Comment: Ted, cold you explain what is happened in Cure's solution? How can other way give us another result?

Comment: The error is in the simplification of the arithmetic. It should be $3843/2$, not $1921$. The problem seems to be that $3^6=729$, not $726$. Calculator error? Human error?